# How can I insert hash into my url within a mapping?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this following mapping:

```
$('#main_menu').find('li').each(function(i, li){
      var $a = $(li).find('>a'),
          url = $a.attr('href'); //http://example.com/category/references

      // code to insert the mark then
      // newUrl = http://example.com/category/#references
});
```

Notice the hash **#references** in the end.

Comment: `str.replace('references', '#references')`…?! That's probably not really what you're asking, is it?!

Comment: It's a mapping so I need to do it dynamically

Comment: you can do something like `urlArr = url.split('/'); urlArr[urlArr.length -1] = \`#${urlArr[urlArr.length -1]}\` `

Comment: FWIW, it's not called a "hashtag mark". That's how the pound sign # is used on social networks. In URLs it's called a *fragment*; or just "hash".

Comment: Why are you trying to add anchors dynamically?

Comment: I tried it from the backoffice but, when I save, it turns back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below the code snippet /***code block****/

```
$('#main_menu').find('li').each(function(i, li){
  var $a = $(li).find('>a'),
  url = $a.attr('href'); //http://example.com/category/references

  /*code block*/
  let to = url.lastIndexOf('/'); to = to == -1 ? url.length : to + 1;  
  newURL = url.substring(0, to) + '#' + url.split("/")[url.split("/").length-1];
  /*code block*/
```

});